# Split vector with overlapping samples in R

Tags: r

Say I have a vector with 1000 values and I want to 'split/partition/group' this vector into multiple vectors each with 200 values and an overlap of 100 values between them.

E.g.:

```
vec = seq(1,1000)
splitWithOverlap(vec, 200, 100)
```

should return the following vectors:

```
[0:200] [100:300] [200:400] [300:500] ...
```

... you get the idea.

Is there a function in R with which I can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but this will do it:

```
splitWithOverlap <- function(vec, seg.length, overlap) {
  starts = seq(1, length(vec), by=seg.length-overlap)
  ends   = starts + seg.length - 1
  ends[ends > length(vec)] = length(vec)

  lapply(1:length(starts), function(i) vec[starts[i]:ends[i]])
}
```

```
> splitWithOverlap(1:100, 20, 10)
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

[[2]]
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

[[3]]
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

[[4]]
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

[[5]]
 [1] 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60

[[6]]
 [1] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70

[[7]]
 [1] 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80

[[8]]
 [1] 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90

[[9]]
 [1]  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

[[10]]
 [1]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: Your answer remains the best, but there is a floor. The last block [10] is not necessary at all. can you please check it out?

Comment: I don t see it unnecessary.  It saved my day! In case you don t need it, just save the list as object (myList) removing the last block myList <- myList[-1]

Answer (score 9):

`rollapply` creates a matrix `m` whose rows are the desired vectors.  Stop at that point omitting last line of code if such result is sufficient; otherwise, if a list of vectors is desired split it by row:

```
library(zoo)

x <- 1:1000  # test input

m <- rollapply(x, 200, by = 100, c)
split(m, row(m))
```

Answer (score 3):

With a little work, you could wrap together the following functions

`?graphics::co.intervals`

```
 co.intervals(vec, 9, 0.5) 
 # then use split, or shingle
```

`?lattice::shingle`

```
 shingle(vec, intervals=co.intervals(vec, 9, 0.5))
```