# R: Split a vector to overlapping subvectors of equal length

Tags: r, split, overlap

Suppose I have a vector 1 to 10 and wish to split it into subvectors of the following two conditions:

1. an equal length of 3.
2. with overlapping of 1.

I got an almost-done answer [Split vector with overlapping samples in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872376/split-vector-with-overlapping-samples-in-r) with a function which I modified bellow:

```
splitWithOverlap <- function(vec, seg.length, overlap) {
  starts = seq(1, length(vec), by=seg.length-overlap)
  ends   = starts + seg.length - 1
  ends[ends > length(vec)] = length(vec)

  lapply(1:length(starts), function(i) vec[starts[i]:ends[i]])
}
splitWithOverlap(1:10, 3, 2)
```

which produced

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4 5

#[[4]]
#[1] 4 5 6

#[[5]]
#[1] 5 6 7

#[[6]]
#[1] 6 7 8

#[[7]]
#[1] 7 8 9

#[[8]]
#[1]  8  9 10

#[[9]]
#[1]  9 10

#[[10]]
#[1] 10
```

**what I want is**

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4 5

#[[4]]
#[1] 4 5 6

#[[5]]
#[1] 5 6 7

#[[6]]
#[1] 6 7 8

#[[7]]
#[1] 7 8 9

#[[8]]
#[1]  8  9 10
```

because the two conditions are achieved and mathematically, `number of blocks = vector length - subvector length + 1` (`10 - 3 + 1`) = 8 and not 10

I want a modification to the function so that it will stop at subvector 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DATA**

```
len = 3
ov = 1
vec = 1:10
```

**1**

```
lapply(1:(length(vec) - (len - ov)), function(i){
    vec[i:(i + len - ov)]
})
```

**2**

```
ind = rep(1:len, length(vec) - (len - ov))
matrix(vec[ind + ave(ind, ind, FUN = seq_along) - 1], ncol = len, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option with `embed` to generate a `matrix` and then split by row with `asplit`

```
n <- 3
n1 <- length(v1)
asplit(embed(c(v1, v1), n)[seq_len(n1- n+1), n:1], 1)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4 5

#[[4]]
#[1] 4 5 6

#[[5]]
#[1] 5 6 7

#[[6]]
#[1] 6 7 8

#[[7]]
#[1] 7 8 9

#[[8]]
#[1]  8  9 10
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 1:10
```

Comment: and also similarly, `n <- 3; v1 <- 1:10; m <- length(v1) - n + 1; split(t(embed(v1, m))[m:1,], 1:m)`